# GWT Page rendering for Search Crawling and Sharing to Social Network Sites

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, gwt

GWT is usually a pure Ajax site. Its contents are created dynamically by Javascript. Thus it poses much problem in terms of Search Crawlability and sharing to Social network sites and other sites.

When sharing my GWT application in a typical Social Network, the "snapshot" or "screenshot" that is generated is just a blank page (typically the background color).

The same is true when trying to add a GWT application in a search index with tools like from Google.

**Question for a home page:**

**Scenario:** The site is `mygwtapp.com`

This page is the home page of the app.

What are the proven ways to make the app (`e.g www.mygwtapp.com`) to be crawled as well as have a rendered site snapshot for use with SNS sharing?

**Question for a dynamic page with a list of stuff to be crawled (like search result):**

**Scenario:** The page is, mygwtapp.com/#PostsPage

This page generates a list to posts, from a Ajax call (RPC or Restlet) then builds the list dynamically.

Clicking a specific post, will forward to a page called, `#PostPage;id=123` this page also contains stuff that crawlers needs to reach.

What are the tweaks to be done for a GWT app such that a search crawler can crawl all the list and each pages thereof.

And again, the same for a home page, what are the ways that the page `mygwtapp.com/#PostPage;id=123` can be shared to SNS sites and get the correct rendered page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/) answers all your questions, although this question is a dupe.